# Chinese Power Supply 180-260v on US 220v Electric

Tags: electrical

I am building 3 large computers each running 3 1300w power supplies.  I purchased the units and I can't return them only to find them in Chinese/AU Power.  The label reads "180v-264v 50-60Hz 20/10A"  In my house, I ran 3 Romex 6/3 wires connected to 60A breakers.  My intention was to hook 3 power supplies to each line.  I ran each of these lines to a disconnect box.  My problem is the power supplies have 3 wires.  Brown hot, Blue natural, and Green/yellow ground.  I have looked into step converters but I don't see any type of product that would let me take the 220v line I have run to the 180-264.  Any suggestions how to proceed or where to find what I need?[image: Power Supply Label]

Comment: Are you using a PDU on each 60A circuit?

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here. But the good news is, you erred on the side of overdesign, so it'll be easy to put it right, and you'll wind up with a fair bit of spare capacity.  For instance, running 6/**3** was a *great* move.  It didn't add much cost and it gave you versatility you can put to good use.

### That power supply

The power supply is rated at 1300W **output**.  One aspect of its cheap Cheeseness and lack of UL listing is that it doesn't have a **nameplate power rating**, or the power it *needs from the power grid*. This differs from output rating by a) power supply efficiency, and b) **power factor**. Skipping the gory details, I'm going to SWAG-guess the **nameplate** at 1800 VA.  The numbers work out reasonably well if I do that.

(feel free to google VA and how it differs from Watts).

Aside from that "reality check", this will be a **continuous load** so we must do a *derate* of 125%.  That means we need to *provision* a circuit for 125% of 1800 VA, or **2250 VA**.

- This is just within the 2400 VA capacity of a 120V/20A circuit.  You would need a step-up transformer, but this would supply correct neutral to the power supply.
- Two would just fit on a 240V/20A circuit (4800 VA)
- only one would fit on a 240V/15A circuit (3600 VA).

Your 60A circuit has 240V x 60A = 14,400 VA.  You won't have any trouble provisioning three 2250W loads on the circuit.  In fact, you could get **six**.

### Powering the units, and neutral

RedGrittyBrick points out a serious issue. These units are made to be connected to hot and neutral.  In USA 240V power, there's no neutral, it's hot and hot. The neutral on the power supply would need to be insulated to tolerate being 120V from ground, and it may not be.  If only the factory could advise you!   Regardless, here's how to fix it.

They make "step-up, step-down" transformers.  You supply 120V at 20A (2400 VA) to the transformer.  It passes the neutral straight through (so that is satisfied). Then it doubles the voltage of the "hot" wire, giving you exactly the right thing: 240V and neutral.

Supplying 120V is possible because you used /3 cable.

### Power distribution off 60A

You can't just hotwire all 3 power supplies to a 60A main, *especially when they're cheap units*. Putting a 1800W unit on a 14,400W circuit breaker is nearly worthless, because the trip point (14,400W) is *so very much* higher than the rating of the power supply (1800W).  You need more sensible breaker sizes.

How to safely split up that 60A supply:

**PDU**. Your first option to distribute power is a **PDU**, which is computer equipment made to sit on the bottom of a rack, take a fat power connection, and distribute it to individual servers in the rack, with sensible circuit protection.   However PDUs are expensive, and subpanels are cheap.

A quality QO panel is about $45, a cheapie BR $22, breakers are $5 or $9 for 240V types.

**Subpanel**.  Normally I recommend the biggest subpanel you can afford.  **But in this case**, there's no use for more than 8-13 spaces (it's rated current must be *at least* 60A).  And then, you fit breakers like this.

- If using step-up transformers, fit 3-6 120V/20A breakers (2400VA each).
- If using 240V, use three 20A breakers (4800 VA) and put up to 2 servers per circuit.
- Or using 240V, use 3-6 15A breakers (3600 VA) with 1 server per circuit.

[image]

*Note in the 120V example, you really have to watch breaker placement for the servers. Place the server breakers in pairs side by side, just like 2-pole breakers. Do not put the 6 server breakers in the top 3 rows. The aux circuit is for small loads like monitors, switches etc.*

Don't parallel.  Use three subpanels.

Neutral and ground must be separated in the subpanel, so add an accessory ground bar ($5) and remove the green screw on the neutral bar to unground it.  This makes 120V available.

Comment: You may be doing those PSUs a disservice.  Assuming it's legitimate the 80+ gold label requires a powerfactor of 0.9 or better (actual 80+ units I've seen reviewed are generally around 0.98 - 0.995 under anything except very light loads) and a minimum efficiency at 220V of 89% for nominal 1600W in derated to 2000W.  Other than meaning that the 60A circuit could theoretically support 7 of them I don't think affects the rest of your analysis.

Comment: @DanNeely oh, I'm sure.  I'd be inclined to trust work out of a xìnyù design bureau like Meanwell or EVGA.  But the gold rush is also an open invitation for bad makers to dump terrible junk, and that's what the markings (and lack of markings, listing, nameplate, even CE! and the markings being inconsistent about whether it can take 120V or not.) makes me think. Also [this](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=hzts+power+supply), it's not in Google unless you enquote "HZTS".  Hence my abundance of caution.

Comment: I mean it might work on 120V. The fact that it says "20/10A input" is inconsistent because there'd be no possible way it would need 20A at 180 or 240V, the power supply would be using up 2kw inside itself, it would blast heat like a hair dryer!  That seems highly unlikely.  But 120/240V 20/10A input would jibe.   Maybe they built it for that range, it failed bench testing and they changed the voltage mark and forgot the current mark. Regardless, 240V@10A should be plenty for an 1800W PS not a 1300W one.  Too many questions.

Comment: True, but again playing devils advocate it could also be because with continuous load derating 80+ gold isn't quite efficient enough to run on a standard 15A-120V circuit; so it's possible they did it deliberately.

Comment: That said I'd also be leery of using it without a review/teardown from a trusted source.  I advise against no-name PSUs at any power level/budget; and for something as expensive and heavily loaded as a mining system would by doubly alarmed.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is the power supplies have 3 wires. Brown hot, Blue natural, and Green/yellow ground.

I highly doubt this is actually a problem for two reasons.

1. Unpolarised plugs are quite common in Europe, so a designer of 240V portable equipment can't reasonably assume that the "neutral" input is actually Neutral.
2. If you have ever looked at the design of a PC power supply, there are maybe a handful of filtering components, then almost immediately a rectifier.

I would have no Qualms about connecting a Euro-spec DC power supply to US style split phase, with one hot connected to the "live" terminal on the power supply and the other hot connected to the "neutral" terminal on the power supply.

My bigger concerns would be.

1. You need appropriate over-current protection, some kind of subpanel or PDU.
2. That power supply is setting off alarm bells of the "cheap Chinese crap" type.

To elaborate on the "Cheap Chineese crap" point.

- The label has no reputable approval markings or standards numbers on it, not even a CE mark (though strangely it does have the ROHS and WEEE logos).
- Googling the make and model finds very little information.
- That "90 plus gold" label is very suspicious, the (somewhat) reputable label for PSU efficiency is "80 plus".
- The warranty void if removed message is written in chinglish.

Answer (score 0):

A power supply with a rating plate that says the input voltage is "180-264V" will work with any voltage which is greater than or equal to 180V and also less than or equal to 264V. Since 220V is within this range, it is fine.

It also says 50-60Hz which means it will work with the frequency used in the USA.

The only concern is that this unit is designed for a single-phase power supply with one hot and a neutral, where neutral is at ground potential. In the USA, a typical 220V supply is split phase with two hots and no neutral. In theory this might make a difference to the insulation required. In practice, I guess you'll probably get away with it. I'd fit a GFCI though because worst case is it bursts into flames or the case is at 120V and electrocutes you.

You might be able to get the correct ground reference using a 220V isolation transformer with a separate ground connection but it might be best to ask about that on electronics.stackexchange.com. if you can phrase the question as an electronic engineering design question.

Since that label doesn't show any kind of UL (or even CE) safety approvals mark I would be especially careful. It might affect your buildings insurance at least.

Comment: I don't believe CE is a safety approval, is it? I just thought it was an unverified promise that it was manufacfured with RoHS solder and stuff like that.

Comment: @Harper its also an unverified promise that it complies with European safety standards. *"The letters ‘CE’ ... signify that products sold in the EEA have been assessed to meet high safety, health, and environmental protection requirements ... By affixing the CE marking to a product, a manufacturer declares that the product meets all the legal requirements for CE marking."* https://ec.europa.eu/growth/single-market/ce-marking_en. So it's arguably weaker than UL but does cover safety. You're right in that its a declaration rather than a putative reference to an approval.

Answer (score 0):

Where's the problem? wiring is 240V/50Hz in UK, just put a socket and plug it to the wall. Recommend 10A fuse fitted in the socket.

If you're American, use a 230V/60Hz line, it's a split-phase system, but basically is the same as having a higher 'phase'. Remember to put on a differential switch to protect you against live-earth breakages. Protect it also with 20A fuse. 4 mm^2 cable will be than enough to run 4 of that at same time.